# C# Is this a case for delegation and callbacks?

Tags: c#

I have an object that handles the logging in of users. This object has a method called LoginPopUp(), which calls Login.show() to display the Login form/window.

The form/window is a seperate object. When a user enters their details and presses submit I want the form to pass data BACK to the calling object. The calling object (the object that handles loging in) will then validate the username and password. If the user is in the database it will close the window.

If the user is not in the database it will remain open and display "incorrect login". So I need a way for the calling object to pass information back to the login window to tell it it's failed.

Im a little confused on how to do this. Is this a case for callbacks and delegation? Whats the conventional solution to use in cases like this? As I'd imagine this happens a lot.

Comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a delegate (aka callback).  Have a delegate typed property of the login form that the caller can set.  You can also do it with an event (which is also a delegate really) and have the login form expose an event that the caller can subscribe to before showing the form.

However, if the same action is always taken after login, then it might be more straightforward to do a direct call instead of using delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will work.

Another simple option is to pass a reference to the user validator to the login window

make the validation function static.

to do what you want here is an ex.
Just create form1 with a text box and form2 with two text boxes and a button to run.

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public bool DoValidate(string username, string password)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("I got called with {0} : {1}",username,password));
            return true;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 F = new Form2(DoValidate);
            F.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}


namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public delegate bool LoginFn(string Uname, string pword);
        private LoginFn m_CallFn;
        public Form2(LoginFn del)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_CallFn = del;
        }

        private void cmdLogon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!m_CallFn(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fail");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Good");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL, pretty much exactly what I just wrote too  :) +1 for great mind

Comment: I would only go this approach if you are going to be making some type of parent class for modal windows and want to be able to reuse some code.

Answer (score 1):

You could achive this in multiple ways

- **using delegate callbacks**
- **using func delegate(inline anonymos methods)**
- **using events**

  ```
  public class FormTest:Form
  {
  public delegate int validateLogin(string userID,string Password);
  public validateLogin validate;
  public event validateLogin validateEvent;
  public void submitWithcallback()
  {
      string userId=string.Empty,pwd=string.Empty;
      validate(userId, pwd);            
  }

  public void submitWithFuncDelegate(Func<string,string,int> funcDelegate)
  {
      string userId = string.Empty, pwd = string.Empty;
      funcDelegate(userId, pwd);           
  }
  public void submitWithEvent()
  {
      string userId = string.Empty, pwd = string.Empty;
      validateEvent(userId, pwd);
  }
  }
  ```

and invoke this from your class

```
   public class Test
   {
        static int validate(string uid, string pwd)
        {
          //your validation code
           return 1;
        }

        void testValidate()
        {

          Func<string, string, int> validateFunc = (uid, pwd) =>
          {
              //your validation code
              return 1;
          };

          FormTest.validateLogin vDel = new FormTest.validateLogin(validate);
          FormTest v1 = new FormTest();
          v1.validate = new FormTest.validateLogin(vDel);
          v1.submitWithcallback();
          v1.submitWithFuncDelegate(validateFunc);

          v1.validateEvent += new FormTest.validateLogin(validate);
          //or with anonymous functions
          v1.validateEvent += (string uid,string pwd)=>{
              //your validation code
              return 1;
          };
          v1.submitWithEvent();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- expose event on Login form, like `LoginSubmitted` with event args that contain the login and password
- expose method on Login form, like `ShowLoginFailed()`
- subscribe to the `LoginSubmitted` event in the controlling object, and handle it by reading the login and password from the event args and checking the database
- if login is successful, close `Login`, otherwise call `ShowLoginFailed()`

Answer (score 0):

Callback/closures will work well here.

Maybe a snippet will help explain.

```
bool CheckUser(string user, string pass) { ... }
```

...

```
void ShowLogin(Func<string,string,bool> check)
{
  var f = new LoginForm();
  f.LoginClick += delegate
  {
    if (check(f.User, f.Pass))
    {
      f.Close();
    }
  };
  f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Usage:

```
ShowLogin(CheckUser);
```